# Java LinkedHashMap converted to Object is serialized as another class?

Tags: java, serialization, linkedhashmap, objectoutputstream

I am trying to serialize a `LinkedHashMap` to be written to an `ObjectOutputStream`, but I've encountered something strange. The `ObjectOutputStream`, writes the `LinkedHashMap` converted to an `Object`, however it is not a `LinkedHashMap`, it is writted as my class called `SQLRow`?!

```
Host.instance.getLogger().info("Sending back player data...");
final LinkedHashMap<String, NetworkedSQLObject> hm = MirageSQLTables.players.getByPrimaryKey(rest.readUTF()).getAsSocketEligibleMap();
Host.instance.getLogger().info("Linked Hash Map class name: " + hm.getClass().getName());
c.sendMessage(new SQLObjectResponsePacket(pID, (Object)hm));
```

NOTE: The function `getByPrimaryKey()` is a custom SQL function that returns my custom class, `SQLRow`.

output of code above:

```
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] Sending back player data...
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] Getting col: id
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] Getting col: name
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] Getting col: date_joined
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] Getting col: rank
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] Getting col: moderator
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] adding NetworkedSQLObject: id:TEXT -> 2
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] adding NetworkedSQLObject: name:TEXT -> KrispWasntTaken
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] adding NetworkedSQLObject: date_joined:TIMESTAMP -> 2023-06-14 18:19:15.0
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] adding NetworkedSQLObject: rank:INT -> 0
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] adding NetworkedSQLObject: moderator:BIT -> true
14:37:03 [INFO] [Host] Linked Hash Map class name: mirage.database.sql.SQLRow$1 <---- HERE!
```

It says the same thing in the NetworkedSQLObject constructor. The function `getAsSocketEligibleMap()` is INSIDE the SQLRow class, but I am really confused as it has no ties to the class and returns a fresh new `LinkedHashMap`, not an instance of a `SQLRow`...

`getAsSocketEligibleMap()` code:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, NetworkedSQLObject> getAsSocketEligibleMap(){
        return new LinkedHashMap<>(){{
            Set<Map.Entry<String, SQLObject>> es = data.entrySet();

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, SQLObject>> i = es.iterator();

            while(i.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry<String, SQLObject> entry = i.next();
                Host.instance.getLogger().info("adding NetworkedSQLObject: " + entry.getKey() + ':' + entry.getValue().getType() + " -> " + entry.getValue().getValue());
                put(entry.getKey(), new NetworkedSQLObject(entry.getValue()));
            }
        }};
    }
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Do you know about a for-each loop? `LinkedHashMap<String, NetworkedSQLObject> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(); for(Map.Entry<String, SQLObject>> entry: data.entrySet()) { Host.instance.getLogger().info("adding NetworkedSQLObject: " + entry.getKey() + ':' + entry.getValue().getType() + " -> " + entry.getValue().getValue()); put(entry.getKey(), new NetworkedSQLObject(entry.getValue())); } return map;` Since Java 8 it’s even simpler: `data.forEach((k,v) -> Host.instance.getLogger().info("adding NetworkedSQLObject: " + k + ':' +v.getType() + " -> " + v.getValue()); put(k, new NetworkedSQLObject(v); }`

Comment: @Holger For my instance, using an iterator retains the order in which the `LinkedHashMap`'s elements were added. This is how I abstract and fill in the data from my SQL response and my objects. a traditional for loop was not working, and without using a `.entrySet().iterator()` it would not be a linear iteration.

Comment: That’s nonsense. The for-each loop uses an `Iterator` under the hood and behaves exactly the same. It’s not even clear what you think it is, if not a linear iteration.

Comment: @Holger, im not sure, but i tried both ways, and was left with a completely unordered iteration order with a for loop.

Comment: I’d like to see a [mre] for that…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the double brace initialization pattern in your class, which is generally not a desirable pattern (the double `{{}}`).  What that does is effectively define a new, inner class.  So you are not returning an actual LinkedHashMap, you are returning an anonymous inner class which extends from LinkedHashMap.  Since it is an inner class, it also retains a reference to the *outer* class, in this case, your `SQLRow` class.  Simply removing the double brace initialization pattern should solve your problem.  (this is one of the many reasons the pattern should be avoided).

Comment: This was an excellent answer, thank you. In future ill try to be more weary of the double brace pattern, I thought that it was just a more compact way to initialize arrays XD. Thanks!